# how to give parcel bundel permission

Tags: reactjs, parcel

i am trying to run this command

```sh
$ parcel client/src/index.html
```

for parcel to build my project but i get the following permission errors

> "Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
>   '/home/adexbam/movie_api/client/src/index.html'"

Comment: this seems like an OS permissions thing, you may need to sudo or change the permissions on your file/directories to allow others to read chmod o+r <dirname>

Comment: thanks, changed it as you directed but still thesame error message